# What causes this "invalid cursor state" error?

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc

An "invalid cursor state" error appears when I run this code.

I use this code to obtain the result set from an Access database, and then store it in a table.

This segment of code is only to obtain the data from the result set:

```
data=new Object[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];
for(int i=0;i<numberOfRows;i++){
  int j=0;
  while(j<numberOfColumns){
    // int colType=rsmd.getColumnType(j+1); 
    // System.out.println(colType);
    data[i][j]=rs.getInt("course_id");
    System.out.print("0th: "+data[i][j]+"    ");
    j++;
    data[i][j]=rs.getString("course_name");
    System.out.print("1st:"+data[i][j]+"    ");
    j++;
    data[i][j]=rs.getString("course_date");
    System.out.print("2nd:"+data[i][j]+"    ");
    j++;
    data[i][j]=rs.getString("course_number");
    System.out.print("3rd: "+data[i][j]+"    ");
    j++;
    System.out.print("j:"+j);
  }
  System.out.print("Done line:"+i);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have some useful debugging output. Please include it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the main problem is that you never call `rs.next()` to scroll the cursor. However, based on your clarification of the record structure, your `while` loop seems messed up too. Try the following:

```
data=new Object[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];
for(int i=0;i<numberOfRows;i++) {
  if (!rs.next())
    throw new IllegalStateException();
  int j=0;
  // int colType=rsmd.getColumnType(j+1); 
  // System.out.println(colType);
  data[i][j]=rs.getInt("course_id");
  System.out.print("0th: "+data[i][j++]+"    ");
  data[i][j]=rs.getString("course_name");
  System.out.print("1st:"+data[i][j++]+"    ");
  data[i][j]=rs.getString("course_date");
  System.out.print("2nd:"+data[i][j++]+"    ");
  data[i][j]=rs.getString("course_number");
  System.out.print("3rd: "+data[i][j++]+"    ");
  while(j<numberOfColumns) {
    data[i][j]=rs.getString(j + 1);
    System.out.print(j+"th: "+data[i][j++]+"    ");
  }
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Done line:"+i);
}
```

Comment: I have one table named by "course" , this table includes 
4 fields which are : "course_id" ,"course_name" ,"course_date" and "course_number"
>> here is how my table looks like:

course_id course_name course_date course_number
data             data             data              data

Comment: >> here is how my table looks like:

course_id course_name course_date course_number
data             data             data              data
data             data             data              data
data             data             data              data
data             data             data              data

i used the first loop to get the number of rows and i used the second loop to get the number of columns and this will help to know the number of coulmns in each row. i can't understand why i don't need it , if i did not use it then i won't be able to get the data !!

Comment: @GhadeerWalid I understand your structure now. It is not what I would have guessed from your code. I will update my answer.

Comment: thank you very much it worked !
but could you please explain this line for me :
 <tab>data[i][j]=rs.getString(j + 1); $

Comment: @GhadeerWalid The JDBC API uses indexes for columns that are 1-based, rather than the 0-based indexes that most programming languages use. So, to obtain the first column (what you call the "0th"), you could use `rs.getInt(1)` instead of `rs.getInt("course_id")`. Since I don't know the names of your "extra" data columns, I just use their index instead; adding one translates the 0-based array index, `j`, to the 1-based JDBC index. And almost any data-type column can be retrieved as a `String`, so I used the `getString()` method to get each field.